# What's the epoch of DateTime(Int64)?

Tags: .net, datetime, epoch

What's the epoch of `DateTime`'s following constructor: [`DateTime(Int64)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`DateTime` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) page on MSDN:

> Time values are measured in
>   100-nanosecond units called ticks, and
>   a particular date is the number of
>   ticks since 12:00 midnight, January 1,
>   0001 A.D. (C.E.) in the
>   GregorianCalendar  calendar (excluding
>   ticks that would be added by leap
>   seconds). For example, a ticks value
>   of 31241376000000000L represents the
>   date, Friday, January 01, 0100
>   12:00:00 midnight. A DateTime value is
>   always expressed in the context of an
>   explicit or default calendar.

The `Int64` parameter is simply the number of ticks, as described above, of course.

Answer (score 1):

- a particular date is the number of
  ticks since 12:00 midnight, January
  1, 0001 A.D. (C.E.) in the
  GregorianCalendar calendar (excluding
  ticks that would be added by leap
  seconds).

From the MSDN [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) entry